# What does it mean to say a single element acts semi-regularly

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on some set $\Omega$. Just a minor point, but saying that some nontrivial element $g \in G$ acts semi-regularly, does this mean that $g$ itself has no fixed point, or that the subgroup generated by $g$ has trivial point stabilizers for each point? I guess the latter, but just to confirm my guess I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition I've seen is that an element is said to be semiregular (or act semiregularly) if it generates a semiregular subgroup. It is not hard to see that this is equivalent to the element having all cycles of the same length, when written as a product of disjoint cycles.

Answer (score 0):

A group $G$ acts semiregularly on a set $X$, if it acts freely, i.e., for $g\in G$, if there exists an $x$ in $X$ with $g.x = x$ (that is, if $g$ has at least one fixed point), then $g$ is the identity. There are several types of group actions, e.g., see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).

Comment: Ok, that is my first interpretation, i.e. that if $g \ne 1$, then it has no fixed points, but this is considerably weaker then asserting that $H := \langle g \rangle$ acts semiregularly. But the article you link does not make it clearer, as there group actions are just defined for *groups*, but what should it mean to have an action for a *single element* then?? Maybe it was not that clear what I was asking, but w.r.t. to your answer I have to ask you what you mean when you say a *single element* acts on some set?(the axioms for group actions do not make sense then as we have no identity)

Comment: If a group $G$ acts, it just means that every *single* $g$ in $G$ acts.